# Multipart upload to S3 with hash verification

Tags: amazon-s3, boto, boto3, s3cmd

I am looking for a command line tool or a Python library which allows uploading big files to S3, with hash verification.

There is an [AWS article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/data-integrity-s3/) explaining how it can be done automatically by supplying a `content-md5` header.

Yet, it is not clear which command line tools do or do not do this:

- [rclone](https://rclone.org/s3/#multipart-uploads)'s documentation states that

  > files uploaded with multipart upload don’t have an MD5SUM.
- [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/usage) doesn't say anything about this, but it supports md5 for the sync feature
- [s4cmd](https://github.com/bloomreach/s4cmd#additional-technical-notes) has a whole paragraph in the manual, but it's still not clear if an upload is actually verified
- boto3 / s3transfer's `upload_file()` method doesn't really say anything

Do you have information about any of these tools, or some other tool or Python library or boto3 snippet which handles big file uploads to s3 with the reliability of rsync?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After asking the authors of the official `aws cli` (boto3) tool, I can conclude that `aws cli` [always verifies every upload](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2585#issuecomment-300601790), including multi-part ones.

It does it chunk-by-chunk, using the official MD5 ETag verification for single-part uploads. Additionally, you can also enable SHA256 verification, still chunk-by-chunk.

`aws cli` does not however verify the whole, assembled file. For that, you'd need to use some tiny Python function for example:

```
def calculate_s3_etag(file_path, chunk_size=8 * 1024 * 1024):
    md5s = []

    with open(file_path, 'rb') as fp:
        while True:
            data = fp.read(chunk_size)
            if not data:
                break
            md5s.append(hashlib.md5(data))

    if len(md5s) == 1:
        return '"{}"'.format(md5s[0].hexdigest())

    digests = b''.join(m.digest() for m in md5s)
    digests_md5 = hashlib.md5(digests)
    return '"{}-{}"'.format(digests_md5.hexdigest(), len(md5s))
```

Comment: Is `chunk_size` an attribute of a multi-part s3 object? How to get the upload `chunk_size` for a already uploaded s3 object?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the TransferConfig to set a chunk size for the upload and then recreate the ETag yourself using the method posted by hyperknot

```
from boto3.s3.transfer import TransferConfig
transfer_config = TransferConfig(multipart_chunksize=8*1024*1024)
```

Pass the transfer_config into the upload_file method

Answer (score 0):

Why not use aws cli? It has support for md5 verification, even for multipart uploads. See [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-multipart-upload-cli/). Both **upload-part** and **put-object** commands of s3api support content verification using hash.

And s4cmd does verify uploads using custom content header containing md5.

As for Etag calculation mentioned in S4cmd doc, see [this](https://www.savjee.be/2015/10/Verifying-Amazon-S3-multi-part-uploads-with-ETag-hash/).

Comment: I am looking for a tested, built in function like `aws s3 cp` or `aws s3 sync` which takes care of the verification, not about writing a custom script to calculate the hashes and to use `s3api`. 

Verifying using the same multipart etag calculation method is an interesting idea though.