Upload large files (multipart) with md5 verification, using same code for both AWS S3 and Alibaba OSS?
I'm hoping to upload (potentially) large files (up to 5 Gig) to both Amazon S3 and Alibaba OSS, with verification - preferably MD5 verification.
My code currently looks like:
#!/usr/bin/env python3.10

"""
This toy program is an exploration of how to do verified, multipart file uploads to AWS S3 and Alibaba OSS.

It's a modified version of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58921396/boto3-multipart-upload-and-md5-checking
"""

import os
import sys
import hashlib

import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from botocore.client import Config
from boto3.s3.transfer import TransferConfig


chunk_size = 2**23


# This function is a re-worked function taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43794838/multipart-upload-to-s3-with-hash-verification
# Credits to user: https://stackoverflow.com/users/518169/hyperknot
def calculate_s3_etag(file_path, chunk_size=chunk_size):
    """Calculate an S3/OSS etag for the file."""
    chunk_md5s = []

    with open(file_path, "rb") as fp:
        while True:
            data = fp.read(chunk_size)

            if not data:
                break

            chunk_md5s.append(hashlib.md5(data))

    num_hashes = len(chunk_md5s)

    if not num_hashes:
        # do whatever you want to do here
        raise ValueError

    if num_hashes == 1:
        return f"{chunk_md5s[0].hexdigest()}"

    digest_byte_string = b"".join(m.digest() for m in chunk_md5s)
    digests_md5 = hashlib.md5(digest_byte_string)

    return f"{digests_md5.hexdigest().lower()}-{num_hashes}"


def s3_md5sum(bucket_name, resource_name, client):
    """Calcuate an MD5 hash for the file."""
    try:
        et = client.head_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=resource_name)["ETag"]
        assert et[0] == '"' and et[-1] == '"'
        return et[1:-1].lower()
    except ClientError:
        # do whatever you want to do here
        raise ClientError


def upload_one_file(
    *,
    filename,
    endpoint_url,
    aws_credentials,
    aws_region,
    bucket,
    addressing_style=None,
):
    """Upload one file to S3.  The file can be up to 5 gigabytes in size, and will be verified on upload."""
    config = {}
    config["region_name"] = aws_region
    if addressing_style:
        config["s3"] = {"addressing_style": addressing_style}
    kwargs = {"config": Config(**config), **aws_credentials}
    if endpoint_url:
        kwargs["endpoint_url"] = endpoint_url
    client = boto3.client("s3", **kwargs)
    transfer_config = TransferConfig(multipart_chunksize=chunk_size)

    client.upload_file(filename, bucket, filename, Config=transfer_config)

    tag = calculate_s3_etag(filename)
    result = s3_md5sum(bucket, filename, client)

    return (tag, result)


class AuthorizationData:
    """Hold things about what S3/OSS to use."""

    def __init__(
        self, *, name, bucket, aws_region, aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, endpoint_url=None, addressing_style=None
    ):
        """Initialize."""
        self.name = name
        self.endpoint_url = endpoint_url
        self.bucket = bucket
        self.aws_region = aws_region
        # self.aws_credentials = aws_credentials
        self.aws_credentials = {
            "aws_access_key_id": aws_access_key_id,
            "aws_secret_access_key": aws_secret_access_key,
        }
        self.addressing_style = addressing_style


def create_test_inputs():
    """Create test files."""
    for filename, blocksize, total_size in (
        ("dastromberg-urandom-1k", 2**10, 2**10),
        ("dastromberg-urandom-16M", 2**20, 2**24),
        ("dastromberg-urandom-256M", 2**20, 2**28),
        ("dastromberg-urandom-1G", 2**20, 2**30),
        ("dastromberg-urandom-5G", 2**20, 5 * 2**30),
    ):
        if not os.path.isfile(filename):
            length_written = 0
            print("Creating test input %s" % filename)
            with (
                open("/dev/urandom", "rb") as infile,
                open(filename, "wb") as outfile,
            ):
                while length_written < total_size:
                    block = infile.read(blocksize)
                    outfile.write(block)
                    len_block = len(block)
                    assert blocksize == len_block
                    length_written += len_block

                assert length_written == total_size

        assert os.path.getsize(filename) == total_size, "Final length does not match. Perhaps remove %s and try again?" % filename


def main():
    """Test some AWS S3- and Alibaba OSS-use."""
    # This works.
    aws = AuthorizationData(
        name="AWS",
        bucket="aaa",
        aws_region="us-west-2",
        aws_access_key_id="bbb",
        aws_secret_access_key=os.environ["aws_secret_key"],
    )

    alibaba = AuthorizationData(
        name="Alibaba",
        # endpoint_url="https://blz-p-cdn-gamepublishing.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/",
        endpoint_url="https://oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com",
        bucket="ccc",
        aws_region="cn-hangzhou",
        aws_access_key_id="ddd",
        aws_secret_access_key=os.environ["alibaba_secret_key"],
        addressing_style="virtual",
    )

    all_good = True

    create_test_inputs()

    for auth in (
        aws,
        alibaba,
    ):
        for filename in (
            "dastromberg-urandom-1k",
            "dastromberg-urandom-16M",
            "dastromberg-urandom-256M",
            # "dastromberg-urandom-1G",
            # "dastromberg-urandom-5G",
        ):
            print(f"Checking {auth.name}: {filename}")
            (tag, result) = upload_one_file(
                filename=filename,
                endpoint_url=auth.endpoint_url,
                aws_credentials=auth.aws_credentials,
                aws_region=auth.aws_region,
                bucket=auth.bucket,
                addressing_style=auth.addressing_style,
            )

            if tag == result:
                print("Verification succeeded: %s, %s" % (tag, result))
            else:
                all_good = False
                print("Verification failed: %s, %s" % (tag, result), file=sys.stderr)

    if all_good:
        print("All tests passed")
    else:
        print("One or more tests failed", file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Running it, AWS S3 verifies for all test inputs, but Alibaba only verifies for the 1 kilobyte test - the 16 megabyte test fails, as do the larger tests.
In https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/en/oss/use-cases/can-i-use-etag-values-as-oss-md5-hashes-to-check-data-consistency Alibaba says that they don't recommend using MD5 for verification.
In https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/en/oss/use-cases/check-data-transmission-integrity-by-using-crc-64 they seem to relatively thoroughly explore using x-oss-hash-crc64ecma.  I'd rather use MD5 (with boto3), but can use crc64ecma if necessary (hopefully with boto3 still).
Has anyone explored this?
Any suggestions?

I dug around in boto's code, and found no mentions of crc64.  There's some crc32 and crc32c, but no crc64.

It turns out Alibaba can be accessed via boto3 if you're willing to upload only small files xor if you're willing to skip verification.
I wound up having to use Alibaba's oss2 module to get both large files and verified uploads.
Here's example code using the oss2 module:
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.10/bin/python3

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
The following code shows how to use data verification when uploading/downloading using MD5.

For MD5 verification, users need to calculate the MD5 value of the uploaded content and put it in the `Content-MD5` of the header.

Note: Resumable upload does not support MD5. Other uploads/downloads support MD5 verification.

Based on https://github.com/aliyun/aliyun-oss-python-sdk/blob/master/examples/object_check.py
"""

import base64
import hashlib
import os
import random
import sys
import tempfile
import warnings

from shared import create_test_inputs

# <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:914: ImportWarning: _SixMetaPathImporter.find_spec() not found; falling back to find_module()
warnings.filterwarnings(
    "ignore",
    category=ImportWarning,
    message=".*_SixMetaPathImporter.find_spec.*not found; falling back to find_module.*",
)
# https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/454 - This isn't boto3, but the issue might be the same.
warnings.filterwarnings(
    "ignore",
    category=ResourceWarning,
    message=".*unclosed <ssl.SSLSocket.*",
)

import oss2


chunk_size = 2**23

# First initialize AccessKeyId, AccessKeySecret, Endpoint and other information.
access_key_id = "<accesskey>"
access_key_secret = os.environ["alibaba_secret_key"]
bucket_name = "<bucket>"
endpoint = "https://oss-accelerate.aliyuncs.com"
# Confirm that the above parameters are filled in correctly
for param in (access_key_id, access_key_secret, bucket_name, endpoint):
    assert "<" not in param, "Please set parameters:" + param


def calculate_file_md5(file_path, blocksize=2**20):
    """Return a base64 eencoded MD5 hash of file_path."""
    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(blocksize), b""):
            hash_md5.update(chunk)
    return base64.b64encode(hash_md5.digest()).decode("UTF-8")


def _prepare_temp_file(content):
    """
    Create a temporary file.

    :param content: file content
    :return file name
    """
    fd, pathname = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix="exam-progress-")
    os.write(fd, content)
    os.close(fd)
    return pathname


def usage(retval):
    """Output a usage message and exit."""
    if retval == 0:
        w = sys.stdout.write
    else:
        w = sys.stderr.write

    w(f"Usage: {sys.argv[0]} --with-md5 --without-md5 --help\n")

    sys.exit(retval)


def main():
    """Start the ball rolling."""
    use_md5 = None
    while sys.argv[1:]:
        if sys.argv[1] == "--with-md5":
            use_md5 = True
        elif sys.argv[1] == "--without-md5":
            use_md5 = False
        elif sys.argv[1] in ("--help", "-h"):
            usage(0)
        else:
            sys.stderr.write(f"{sys.argv[0]}: unrecognized option: {sys.argv[1]}\n")
            usage(1)
        del sys.argv[1]

    if use_md5 is None:
        sys.stderr.write(f"{sys.argv[0]}: you must specify one of --with-md5 or --without-md5\n")
        usage(1)

    create_test_inputs()

    # Create a Bucket object. All Object-related interfaces can be accessed through the Bucket object
    bucket = oss2.Bucket(oss2.Auth(access_key_id, access_key_secret), endpoint, bucket_name)

    all_good = True

    for filename in (
        "dastromberg-urandom-1k",
        "dastromberg-urandom-16M",
        "dastromberg-urandom-256M",
        "dastromberg-urandom-1G",
        "dastromberg-urandom-5G",
    ):
        print(f"Checking Alibaba: {filename}", flush=True)
        try:
            key = upload_one_file(bucket=bucket, filename=filename, use_md5=use_md5)
        except (oss2.exceptions.ClientError, oss2.exceptions.ServerError, oss2.exceptions.RequestError):
            print("Verification failed")
            all_good = False
        else:
            print("Verification succeeded")
            # We don't want to clutter up the test storage.
            bucket.delete_object(key)

    if all_good:
        print("All tests passed")
    else:
        print("One or more tests failed", file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)


def random_string():
    """Return a random string."""
    return "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k=16))


def upload_one_file(*, filename, bucket, use_md5, disambig=None):
    """Upload one file, multipart, with optional MD5 check."""
    if disambig is None:
        key = filename
    elif disambig == "pid":
        key = filename + str(os.getpid())
    elif disambig == "random":
        key = filename + random_string()
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"disambig had a strange value: {disambig}")

    headers = {}

    if use_md5:
        md5_hash = calculate_file_md5(filename)
        headers["Content-MD5"] = md5_hash

    bucket.put_object_from_file(filename, filename, headers=headers)
    return key


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

